# Generating a tree that may have branches that terminate [Python]

Tags: python, tree

I'm trying to create a script that will generate a tree in the following way: if number is ever: split into 3 numbers: number // 2, number * 2, number + 15. If number is odd: split into 2 numbers: number +1, number * 4. These branches continue until a branch is either: greater than 100, equal to 6, a perfect square (square root of number is an integer). I'm having a problem with having either 2 or 3 branches for different conditions. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,number,parent):
        self._parent = parent
        self._number = number
        self._satisfied = number > 100 or number == 6 or np.sqrt(number) % 1 == 0
        self._branch1 = None
        self._branch2 = None
        self._branch3 = None
        self._depth = parent.depth + 1 if parent != None else 1

    @property
    def parent(self):
        return self._parent

    @property
    def number(self):
        return self._number

    @property
    def satisfied(self):
        return self._satisfied

    @property
    def depth(self):
        return self._depth

    @property
    def branch1(self):
        return self._branch1

    @branch1.setter
    def branch1(self,value):
        self._branch1 = value

    @property
    def branch2(self):
        return self._branch2

    @branch2.setter
    def branch2(self,value):
        self._branch2 = value

    @property
    def branch3(self):
        return self._branch3

    @branch3.setter
    def branch3(self,value):
        self._branch3 = value

def print_all_chains(node,chain=[]):
    if node.branch1 is None:
        chain.append(node.number)
        print '{0}: {1}'.format(node.satisfied, chain)
    else:
        print_all_chains(node.branch1, chain[:] + [node.number])
        print_all_chains(node.branch2, chain[:] + [node.number])
        print_all_chains(node.branch3, chain[:] + [node.number])

def make_daughters(number):
    if number % 2 == 0: #even
        daughters = [number // 2, number * 2, number + 15]
    else:
        daughters = [number + 1, number * 4, None]
    return daughters

def build_tree(node, maxDepth):
    if not node.satisfied and node.depth<maxDepth:
        daughters = make_daughters(node.number)
        node.branch1 = Node(daughters[0], node)
        build_tree(node.branch1,maxDepth)
        node.branch2 = Node(daughters[1], node)
        build_tree(node.branch2,maxDepth)
        node.branch3 = Node(daughters[2], node)
        build_tree(node.branch3, maxDepth)

def find_decay(number):
    root = Node(number,None)
    build_tree(root,maxDepth=3)
    print_all_chains(root)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    find_decay(int(raw_input('Number: ')))
```

Comment: "I'm having a problem with having either 2 or 3 branches for different conditions" - not clear enough: what is the sequence of numbers you've used and what error are you getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a list to keep the branch information? Then it can be rewritten into this way without adding a **None** type element in the two branch situation.

```
daughters = make_daughters(node.number)
node.branch = [Node(d, node) for d in daughters]
```

Without worries about **None** type elements

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the odd case when you `make_daughters`: you're adding a `None` as the third parameter and later on you're creating a new `Node` and try to run the `sqrt` method on `None`.

The following parts were modified to fix this issue:

```
def print_all_chains(node,chain=[]):
    if node.branch1 is None:
        chain.append(node.number)
        print '{0}: {1}'.format(node.satisfied, chain)
    else:
        if node.branch1:  # print only if it's a valid branch
            print_all_chains(node.branch1, chain[:] + [node.number])
        if node.branch2:  # print only if it's a valid branch
            print_all_chains(node.branch2, chain[:] + [node.number])
        if node.branch3:  # print only if it's a valid branch
            print_all_chains(node.branch3, chain[:] + [node.number])

def make_daughters(number):
    if number % 2 == 0: #even
        daughters = [number // 2, number * 2, number + 15]
    else:
        daughters = [number + 1, number * 4]  # don't send None
    return daughters

def build_tree(node, maxDepth):
    if not node.satisfied and node.depth<maxDepth:
        daughters = make_daughters(node.number)
        node.branch1 = Node(daughters[0], node)
        build_tree(node.branch1,maxDepth)
        node.branch2 = Node(daughters[1], node)
        build_tree(node.branch2,maxDepth)
        if len(daughters) > 2: # make sure you have the third element
            node.branch3 = Node(daughters[2], node)
            build_tree(node.branch3, maxDepth)
```